# How to validate input in formGroup, declared in another formGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```html
<form id="wrapped" [formGroup]="multiformDetails" (onSubmit)="getUserDetails();">
    <div class="step wizard-step" [hidden]="step2" formGroupName="fullNamedetails">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label><strong>Do you want to post anonymously ?</strong></label>
          <div class="switch">
             <input id="cmn-toggle-4" class="form-control cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-flat"
                type="checkbox" (change)="checktoggle()">
             <label for="cmn-toggle-4"></label>
          </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <h5><strong>1/11</strong></h5>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label>
             <h5>Full Name <span class="text-danger">*</span> </h5>
          </label>
          <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control valid required" placeholder="Full Name"
             formControlName="fullName">
       </div>
       <div id="bottom-wizard">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="button" name="forward" class="forward right-btn"
                (click)="step2 = true;step3 = false"
                [disabled]="fullnamevalid && !fullNamedetails.valid">Next</button>
                <button type="button" name="backward" class="backward right-btn mr-15"
                   (click)="step2 = true;step1 = false">Prev</button>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm trying to enable the next button when the input field is validated. I had placed a form group called 'fullName' within another form group called 'multiformDetails'.

**TS file:**

```js
multiformDetails = new FormGroup({

    fullNamedetails: new FormGroup({
      fullName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    }),

    emailId: new FormGroup({
      emailid: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    })
})
```

Comment: When the inner formGroup is valid, then the parent one will be valid. What exact issue you have, can you add what you have already tried in you typescript file ?

Comment: I'm working on a multistep form. When an input field is empty the next button should be disabled. So I had included each step form fields within a formGroupName = "fullNamedetails " and checked for there(!fullNamedetails.valid) validation to enable the next button. And finally, I wrapped the entire multiform in form tags with another [formGroup]  = "multiformDetails ".

Answer (score 0):

Check this working example, when the inner `fullNamedetails` form group is valid then the parent form group will be valid.

[Stack stackblitz example for formgroup validation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-dvc8sk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

I've added the `required` directive for the checkbox input button,
and added a `Validators.required` for full name input.

when you load first the page, the Next button is disabled, and then you have to check the checkbox and provide the name in order to have the Next button enabled.

**You have to group the checkbox control and fullName control inside the inner form group.**